# How to Read and Write a plist that works like iphone note apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

Hi I'm New in iphone programming and i need some help.

I will like to create a notepad alike apps to enable user to write and save their notes, similar to the iphone note apps using plist, it is possible ?

similar to the iphone apps, that i'm able to list out all the notes i have created, it is possible.

The design is not important for my apps cos is just for me to learn.

Is there anyone could guide me to a good tutorial?

I Thank You guys in advances for replying, any reply will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by saving the text in your textview to a .txt file.

```
//NotesViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface NotesViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextView *textView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;

-(void)loadNotes;
-(void)saveNotes;

@end



//NotesViewContoller.m

#import "NotesViewController.h"


@implementation NotesViewController

@synthesize textView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
     textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
     self.view = textView;
     [self loadNotes];
}

-(void)loadNotes {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedText.txt"];
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIColor *clear = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0];
    textView.backgroundColor = clear;
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0];
    textView.text = text;
}

-(void)saveNotes {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *textToSave = [textView text];

    if (textToSave == nil || textToSave.length == 0) {
        textToSave = @"";
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedText.txt"];
    [textToSave writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

That should work, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: note that right now there is nothing to call saveNotes, so unless you add a button or something that calls that, your notes wont be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible ;)

The easiest way for storing data is using NSUserDefaults.

So lets say you have a note:

```
NSString *mynote = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My first note"];
```

and want it to put save it, then you do:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefs setObject:myNote forKey:@"kMyNote"];
```

but you will have to a key for each note, which is not desirable ;)

So you can create an NSArray and put your notes there:

```
//inmutable, cannot be changed later
NSArray *notes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNote, nil];

//or you can try with mutable arrays
//NSMutableArray *notes = [NSMutableArray array]; 
//[array addObject:myNote];
//[array addObject:myNote2];//, add more elements as needed

//save them
[userDefs setObject:notes forKey:@"kNotes"];
```

and when you want to get the values again:

```
NSArray *savedNotes = [userDefs objectForKey:@"kNotes"];
```

Be aware that you store NSArrays.  Even if you stored an NSMutableArray with "kNotes", later you will get an inmutable NSArray.

Please read further on [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) since there are some restrictions on the kind of objects you can and cannot store.

You can use this approach to store the text itself or maybe to store paths of files like in  @Jumhyn example.

If you wan't to get serious about this you will find CoreData much more useful and eficient ;)

Hope it helps

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` should really only be used for saved settings. If there's document-like data to persist, saving to disk or into Core Data is much more efficient. Doing one of the latter two can also be more flexible – for instance, you can enable document sharing to allow the user to copy notes to their computer.